# Can we save a value in a config file in unix, which would display as XXXX when opened with vi or more/ cat. But still has a different actual value

Tags: unix, passwords, aix

I want to store a password in a config file, something as below. I want my scripts to use it. But
when The config file is opened using vi or more or cat, it should display as 'XXXXX' but not its actual value.

```
PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: I'm afraid there's no such way.

Comment: You could use encryption with a master password.

Comment: If your script can get and use the clear text password then other programs or scripts (running as the same user) can do this as well. Please [edit] your question and add details what you want to achieve and for what purpose the password will be used in your scripts. Maybe there are different ways to do what you need. File permissions? Key based authentication? Hash functions?

Answer (score 0):

## A simple implementation:

#### Input file

```
LOGIN=foobar
PASSWORD=YouDontKnowMeIamSecret
lorem
ipsum 
doloris
```

#### Your cat implementation with required feature:

```
alias mycat="sed -E 's/^(PASSWORD=).*/\1XXXXXX/'"
```

then

```
mycat file
```

#### Output

```
LOGIN=foobar
PASSWORD=XXXXXX
lorem
ipsum 
doloris
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the UNIX/Linux way. Which mean you can store the hash of the password in config file, something like:

```
LOGIN=foobar
PASSWORD=6b3a55e0261b0304143f805a24924d0c1c44524821305f31d9277843b8a10f4e
lorem
ipsum 
doloris
```

and when user/program want to use it provide the password `password` and a program, script do `sha256` over this string and compare the result with the value, stored in config

This above is just a example and you should implement additional measures to avoid rainbow tables attack for example.

Comment: A "fast" hash like SHA256 is not recommended for password storage - algorithms that salt and stretch (add rounds / work factors) are the minimum. The example hash above is currently 'password', but anything in the top *billion* of leaked passwords would fall within minutes on even a semi-modern GPU. bcrypt, Argon2, and yescrypt are some modern recommendations, but even md5crypt with sufficient rounds would be dramatically better than a straight fast hash.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams, this is just a example, hash can be any, can be salted, etc :)

Comment: That's reasonable - but StackOverflow readers may be new, or in a hurry, etc. - and might not realize that the example should not be followed exactly. :D

Comment: @RoyceWilliams, `md5` better than `sha256`? Also I can't satisfy the World. If someone copy/paste blindly this is not my problem.

Comment: Raw MD5 (which is different from md5crypt, which has salt and stretching) would be no better than SHA256 - actually worse, because MD5 is a faster hash to attack. 
These comments - or maybe also an edit with something like "this is just an example, passwords should be strongly hashed when stored" - seems like enough. You're right - there's only so much as we can do. :D